# Why are some sent mails shown in Inbox and some not?

Tags: gmail

Majority of the emails I send are not only shown in `Sent` folder, but also in the main `Inbox`. But, some are not. Why? I cannot figure out the rule. It's not attachment.

I was wondering if there was some mistake, when the mail doesn't appear in `Inbox`, and whether it has been sent.

Comment: Are the ones that end up in the inbox replies?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of a tag. I know that I have 'lost' emails and they have been tagged unexpectedly.

You might also check if there are any filters in place. Settings > Filters and blocked addresses.

Answer (score -1):

It might have to do with the conversation view. Try turning it off (or on). Hope that helps!